# mongo query in pyspark to pull data greater than certain date which is string ISODate format

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

Here is the sample fields from mongo docs which show how the time format is in.

```
{
    "_id" : "810122000273",
    "applicationTimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-11-1T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Out of my research I have written the following query in the spark pipeline using pyspark as shown

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{'applicationTimeStamp':{
              "$gte": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},ISODate("2020-11-01T00:00.000Z")]
            }}}]
```

As the ISODate is related to mongoDB, how can I write it in pyspark, Wanted to pull the mongo docs after `2020-11-1T00:00:00.000Z`

```
df_pipeline = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
                             .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:pass@abc.com:27017/DBReport.Application")\
                             .option("pipeline", pipeline).load()
```

Let me know, where am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `pipeline = [{'$match':{'applicationTimeStamp':{'$gte': {'$date': "2020-11-01T00:00.000Z" }}}}]`?

Comment: I have also tried this query, It didn't work, It throws this error

 requirement failed: Invalid Aggregation map Map(uri -> mongodb://user:pass@abc.com:27017/DBReport.Application, pipeline -> [{'$match': {'applicationTimeStamp': {'$gte': {'$date': '2020-11-01T00:00.000Z'}}}}])